# Generic Restful client that read Service url from config file using jersey

Tags: java, jersey, restful-url

I have a restful api using Jersey. In my client I am using `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client`.

```
WebResource webResource2 = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/RestJersey/restful/service1");
```

Instead of hardcoding service url I want to read it from config file. So that it can be changed without need to recompile and whole nine yards. Also it is generic.

Answer (score 0):

Create configuration file and write to it your service url, then load it and retrieve url:

```
...
Properties properties = new Properties();
String configFileName = "...";
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(configFileName);

properties.load(inputStream);

String serviceUrl = properties.getProperty("service.url");
...
```